# Have second okHTTP request wait for the first to finish Android

Tags: java, api, android-studio, okhttp

I am trying to call and IMDb API 2 times, the first time it calls and gets the ID for that movie/show and the second time it uses that ID to get all the information about that movie/show, I also need that ID for another part of the app so that is why I am doing it this way. The problem is that the second call isn't waiting for the first call to be done. I think this is why the variables aren't updated when I am trying to use them. This is my onCreate method where all this is happening, I took out some of the API key for obvious reasons:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imdb_activity);

        mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);

        OkHttpClient client1 = new OkHttpClient();
        //change the url to be generic and usable for user input
        String urlforID = "https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/?page=1&r=json&s=Avengers";
        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(urlforID)
                .get()
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com")
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "KEYGOESHERE")
                .build();
        client1.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException
            {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    try
                    {
                        myObj = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        myArray = myObj.getJSONArray("Search");

//                responseID = new String[myArray.length()];//might have to subtract 1

                        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject obj1 = myArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            responseID[i] = obj1.getString("imdbID");
//                            Log.d("id","the id that was just put in was: " + responseID[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    imdb_activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            //new ReadJsonForID().execute();
                            Log.d("id", "The id is: " + responseID[0]);
                            mTextViewResult.setText(responseID[0]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
//this is where call 2 would happen but it is not saving the variable how it should
            Log.d("id", "The id is after finish: " + mTextViewResult.getText());
```

Comment: How to you execute the second call? The code-snippet just shows one call.

Comment: @J.Gerbershagen I do practically the same thing, like make the call and then execute it outside the body of the first one, so that it's just inside the onCreate(). Should I do the second call from inside the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CountDownLatch`-class in package `java.util.concurrent`. In the first call, the `countDownLatch` is instantiated and in the second call, you await the `CountDownLatch`. This maybe require to put the second task in an `AsyncTask`.