# How do you handle multiple okhttp requests that the next relies on the previous?

Tags: android, okhttp

I have a number of requests that rely on the previous ones..
How you handle this in an elegant readable way ?

I could call each one in the callback of the previous app but that will 
create an indentation nightmare.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60792549/have-second-okhttp-request-wait-for-the-first-to-finish-android/60809583#60809583

Comment: @J.Gerbershagen ok thanks!